# Remove second part of file name from files in a series of folders

Tags: bash, unix

I have a series of folders (about a 100) with a set of files that look like the following:

```
Folder 1:
species_2136.dbf
species_2136.lyr
species_2136.prj
species_2136.sbn
species_2136.sbx
species_2136.shp
species_2136.shp.xml
species_2136.shx

Folder 2:
species_136524.dbf
species_136524.lyr
species_136524.prj
species_136524.sbn
species_136524.sbx
species_136524.shp
species_136524.shp.xml
species_136524.shx
```

I'd like everything to be named `species.ext`. How can I remove the `_####` from all files in all folders to look like this?

```
Folder 1:
species.dbf
species.lyr
species.prj
species.sbn
species.sbx
species.shp
species.shp.xml
species.shx

Folder 2:
species.dbf
species.lyr
species.prj
species.sbn
species.sbx
species.shp
species.shp.xml
species.shx
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In [`bash` parameter expansion](http://wiki.bash-hackers.org/syntax/pe),

```
for file in ./{folder1,folder2}/*
do
    mv "$file" "${file%_*}"."${file#*.}"
done
```

(or) in a single line as

```
for file in ./{folder1,folder2}/*; do mv "$file" "${file%_*}"."${file#*.}"; done
```

loop can also be done as,

```
for file in ./folder1/* ./folder2/*; do mv "$file" "${file%_*}"."${file#*.}"; done
```

Answer (score 1):

With Perl‘s rename (standalone command):

```
rename -n 's/_[0-9]+//' "Folder "*/species*
```

If everything looks fine, remove option `-n`.

Answer (score 0):

**your files names**

```
species_2136.dbf  
species_2136.lyr  
species_2136.prj  
species_2136.sbn  
species_2136.sbx  
species_2136.shp  
species_2136.shp.xml  
species_2136.shx
```

Very easy and simple to do by `rename` command. First go to your **folder** and then try this:
`rename -n 's/_.*?\./\./'`

Here `-n` is for no action and just show the output to you
The tricky part is this regex: `_.*?\.` and it match everything from `_` to `.` for once. and the substitute them with a single dot `.` that's it.

**Prove**

```
$ cat your-list-of-file | rename -n 's/_.*?\./\./'  
rename(species_2136.dbf, species.dbf)   
rename(species_2136.lyr, species.lyr)    
rename(species_2136.prj, species.prj)  
rename(species_2136.sbn, species.sbn)  
rename(species_2136.sbx, species.sbx)  
rename(species_2136.shp, species.shp) 
rename(species_2136.shp.xml, species.shp.xml)  
rename(species_2136.shx, species.shx)
```